# Enthought Canopy some keyboard shortcuts not working

Tags: enthought

I'm using Canopy (1.1.0 64-bit on Mac OSX 10.8) to create IPython notebooks and I noticed some keyboard shortcuts are not working. While `Command+C` and `Command+X` work as expected, paste (`Command+V`) and the cell shortcuts (e.g. `Ctrl+m m` for converting the cell to markdown) are not working.

For `Command+V`, it makes the cursor jump to the beginning of the cell instead of pasting, so I'm assuming it's been set somewhere to something different than paste. Is there a way to remap it back to paste?

Comment: try using the 'Fn" key instead of control. I have no idea why but on my macbook to perform a basic line insertion (above or below) I have to hit Fn + A and Fn + B respectively. The keyboard shortcuts documentation says to hit Ctlr + A or Ctrl + B but that doesn't seem to be the case on my macbook.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before, which has been solved by installing newer version of Enthought Canopy (>=1.4). See the following link for details. Hope this helps!

https://support.enthought.com/entries/21742524-OSX-Pasting-to-the-notebook